# Isn't it time to change the page advance system?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, users, pagination

On SO, the number of questions and users has grown significantly.  So much so that if I want to look at pages further down the line, I can only show 50 questions per page, and the page advancers only move up to 2 pages at a time.  I am working if there will be a goto page option, or increase the number of questions per page, or increase the amount you can click to (by like 10 pages or so)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why this would look almost like an oversight during the initial design period. Jonathan did show that it was possible to skip around via the url, but I don't think it would be too much to ask to have a page number selector in the page listing either.

Comment: Don't make me get my greasemonkey out! :)

Comment: Hmm... Any other site (including future SE sites), i could see that. But is it *really* too much to ask that **programmers** understand how to edit URLs?

Comment: Its really more a question of usability.  Surely we could drop all the page advancing options and just use the url... but is it really to much to ask programmers to implement a small change to create a better UI?

Answer (score 2):

You can *go to page*:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=1&sort=newest

Just edit the `page` value.

Comment: Ha, yeah I guess I could do that, but it sure would be nice to have something on the site, but that could do