# Can I index into question list by question index instead of page number?

Tags: feature-request, search

Being new to SO I am sharing my knowledge by upvoting both questions and answers on all questions for a tag I am knowledgeable on and adding new answers when I believe I have a better answer.

Since I have limited upvotes, I have to stop in the middle of the list each day and manually mark down where I am at, which is the page number because of the way the system was designed, and the title of the question on the page.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog?page=26&sort=newest&pagesize=200

I know about [setting page index manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3851/181143)
and [search options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

If I could just index into the list by question index, not global question number

> ?question=1331&sort=newest&pagsize=200

and have the question index appear next to the question title then it would be a lot easier to keep track of where I am, and get back to where I was.

If the feature exists, just point me to it.

If there is a page that explains **all** of the query options for SO, that would be even better.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding here, but since you're on the newest tab, the index would still be off when returning the next day (more new questions inserted at the start), right?

Comment: @nickCraver If you are starting with the newest question as index 1 then yes, however if you start with the oldest question as index 1, the numbers should be correct, because old questions are not deleted. Newer questions get higher index numbers. If you are implying that it should be sort=oldest and then taking the oldest to have index = 1, that is understandable.

Comment: that's what I'm confused about...we have no oldest sort anywhere that I'm aware of, for this to make sense it seems to be predicated on *that* feature being added as well.

Comment: I still don't grasp what exactly you're asking for...a "sort by oldest" will not be added though, it's such a rare use case we can't justify the real-estate, especially since going to the last page gets that behavior.  You *can* get what you're after via the API though, which has more sorting options (and can be restricted based on date).

Comment: @NickCraver Yes that would have to be added also. I don't know the inner workings of the query engine, so I can only guess at what it does.

Comment: @NickCraver Can you give a link to the API?

Comment: absolutely, https://api.stackexchange.com/ also, http://stackapps.com/ is specifically for this sort of thing, may want to check it out for examples.